# Pointer to array of objects require public destructor

Tags: c++

I can't understand why the compiler doesn't allow to define a pointer to the dynamic array of objects, which have private destructor (outside the actual class or object of this type).

At the same time, the definition of a pointer to a single dynamic object of this kind (the one with private destructor) is perfectly valid.

Here goes the code sample:

```
class P
{
public:
    P()
    {
        std::cout << "Construct P" << "\n";
    }

    static P * GetStatic10()
    {
        return new P[10]; // Compiled fine.
    }

    P * Get10()
    {
        return new P[10]; // Compiled fine.
    }

private:
    ~P()
    {
        std::cout << "Destroy P" << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    P *p1_0 = new P(); // Compiled fine.
    P *p2 = new P[10]; // Compile error: "Calling a private destructor of class 'P'".

    return 0;
}
```

To clarify, the question is about this line of code: `P *p2 = new P[10];`.

NOTE: Compiled in Xcode 10.0 (Default compiler: Apple Clang).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine that constructor of second object in array fails, then first one needs to be destructed. So destructor will be used in the compiler-emitted code that handles cleanup in case of array initialization failure.

Comment: Well, then why the same rule doesn't apply to a single constructed object? E.g. some the constructor partially performed initialization and failed after that. Doesn't the destructor need to be called in this case?

Comment: @Max Because if  construction of a single object fails, no destructor is called, as the object was never successfully constructed.

Comment: @Max Destructor needs to be called only after object is successfully constructed.